# Что за кодировка ANSI в Notepad++

Tags: кодировка, ansi

Открыл Notepad++. Там есть возможность преобразовать в ANSI. Непонятно, что в этой программе подразумевается под кодировкой ANSI, ведь такой кодировки вроде как несуществует. Насколько я знаю ANSI - это неофициальное обобщенное название кодировок windows 1251, windows 1252, ascii(7bit).

Так в какую кодировку будет преобразован текст ?

Comment: «графических» кодировок `"125?"` значительно больше, чем две. вероятно, будет выбрана та, что соответствует текущей [локали](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C).

Answer (score 7):

В Windows под [ANSI codepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) обычно понимается «системная» кодировка. Она используется для не-юникодных программ (и кажется для не-юникодных файловых систем). Для стандартной американской версии это CP 1252, для русской — CP 1251.

Хотя название и ссылается на стандарт ANSI, реально оно ничего общего со стандартом не имеет.

Чаще всего это *однобайтная* кодировка, но для некоторых систем (например, японской) это [MBCS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z097dxa.aspx).

Следует различать ANSI-кодировку (используемую для не-юникодных Windows-программ) и OEM-кодировку (используемую для не-юникодных DOS-программ, в случае русской Windows это CP 866).

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите ответ на ваш вопрос в официальной [документации.](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Convert_Or_Encode%3F#In_ANSI:)

Answer (score 1):

> Насколько я знаю ANSI - это неофициальное обобщенное название кодировок windows 1251, windows 1252, ascii(7bit). Так в какую кодировку будет преобразован текст ?

Насколько я помню, там подразумевается общая их часть. Т. е. однобайтовая кодировка, со всеми кодами до 128. Всё, что вне этой области, превратится в вопросы.